# Jquery-Delete all the row if first td of row does not have the id with given value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with many rows. from which i want to delete all the rows except the row, of which first td has a given id.

i am in half way

```
 <tr>
   <td id="1" class="td_link" onclick="viewPointDetails(1)">Barrackpur</td>
   <td class="td_link" id="11" class="edit_client" onclick="editPoint(1)">India</td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
   <td id="2" class="td_link" onclick="viewPointDetails(2)">Madiwala</td>
   <td class="td_link" id="11" class="edit_client" onclick="editPoint(1)">India</td>
 </tr>
```

​

and my jquery;

```
   $('tr').each(function () {   
       if first td does not have given  id say 1  then delete this row.
   });
```

my First row is header. so i dont want this to be checked(do not want this row to be deleted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this without the `each` loop:

```
$("tr:not(:has(#1))").remove();
```

This uses the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to return rows which contain an element matching the selector. It uses the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to get the opposite of that (so you end up with all rows that do *not* contain an element matching the selector), and then uses [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove all elements in the matched set.

Comment: Perfect James.. my First row is header. so i dont want this to be checked(do not want this row to be deleted).. How can i do that??

Comment: Have a look at the `:gt` selector in the jQuery API. You should be able to add that in to the example in my answer.

Comment: if i passing the id as variable for e.g instead of value 1 its variable called pointId (pointId = 1) then how the above code changes??

Comment: `$("tr:gt(0):not(:has(#" + pointId + "))").remove();` - The selector is just a string, so you can concatenate it like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('tr').each(function () {   
      if($(this).find("td:first").attr("id") == 2)
      {
        $(this).remove();
      }
  });
});
```