# Remove all the 'tr' if the any of the 'td' does not have given text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with many rows . first row is the header.

i want to delete all the rows if any of its td does not have given text.

```
<tr>
     <td id="1" class="links">Madia</td>
     <td id="" class="edit_client" >Press</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="2" class="td_link" >Nagara </td>
    <td class="td_link" id="11" class="edit_client">KR Pura</td>
</tr>
```

I want to delete all the tr , if any of its td does not have given text say "me hussy".

```
 $('tr').each(function () { 

 });
```

i do not want delete first row because its header. so function should check from second row onwards.

Comment: similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412995/jquery-delete-all-the-row-if-first-td-of-row-does-not-have-the-id-with-given-val

Comment: For your new query you can post new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this

```
$('table tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
   if ($('td:contains("me hussy")', this).length == 0) $(this).remove();
});​
```

[Demo on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ANC2F/2/)

**EDIT:**

Thanks mesiesta for `:gt(0)`

**EDIT**

With respect to OP's comment

```
var name = "me hussy";
$('table tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
   if ($('td:contains("'+ name +'")', this).length == 0) $(this).remove();
});​
```

Comment: I want to delete all the tr , if ***any*** of its td does not have given text say "me hussy".

Comment: So all `td` should contain the text "me hussy" for the table rows not to be deleted? ;/

Comment: @AmarPalsapure: OP's comment above should clarify it hopefully.

Comment: In the question it is mentioned that all the `tr` needs to be deleted if their `td` doesn't contain `me hussy`. Secondly OP didn't comment on any of the answer.

Comment: what if i am passing name as variable for ex: Var name = "me Hussy"

Comment: i have a table with many rows . i am using pagination to shows 10 entries per page. this function working for the data present in first page. is there any work around to make this function to work for all the pages even if i am seaching it from first page.

Comment: Do you all rows on client side, or in paging you retrieve it from server using Ajax call?

Answer (score 3):

```
var name="me hussy";
$('tr').not(':first').not($('tr').find('td:contains('+name+')').parent()).remove()
```

Comment: what if i am passing name as variable for ex: Var name = "me Hussy"

Comment: Edited my answer to handle that. The "var name" row is just to show such variable.

Comment: No it won't work http://jsfiddle.net/ANC2F/4/ `$('tr').not(':first').not($('tr').find('td:contains('+name+')').parent()).remove()` will

Comment: I can't see any difference to my current version. Perhaps you saw the version I had there for a minute, which had 'td:contains(name)' instead of the current.

Comment: i have a table with many rows . i am using pagination to shows 10 entries per page. this function working for the data present in first page. is there any work around to make this function to work for all the pages even if i am seaching it from first page.

Comment: If you have the data available in the page already but just hidden, this should work for that too. If you fetch the other pages using AJAX or something similar, just do this every time you add new data to the page.

On the other hand, why not then do that on the server side rather than in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('tr:not(:contains("me hussy")):not(:first)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `thead` and `tbody` to separate the rows but this should work;

```
$(function() {
    var $table = $('table#byID');
    var $bodyRows = $table.find('tr').not(':first'); // Exclude the first row
    var hasEmptyTds = $bodyRows.find('td').filter(function() { // Filter by text, could also use the :contains selector
        return ($(this).text() != 'me hussy')
    }).length > 0;

    if (hasEmptyTds) {
        $bodyRows.remove(); // Remove all table body rows
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-use the functionality, wrap it in a function, otherwise you can just replace the `mustMatchString` in the jQuery line below. To remove the first item, use the jQuery `.slice` method.

```
function runRemoval(mustMatchString) {
   jQuery('tr').slice(1).each(function() {
       if(!jQuery('td:contains("' + mustMatchString + '")', this).length) {
           jQuery(this).remove();
       }

   });
}

runRemoval('me hussy')​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/D6Hkh/